# Generating all possible binary trees given n leaves

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree, permutation

So as the title suggests anyone has/ knows of an algorithm (in java if possible)to generate all possible binary trees given the number of leaves as in the example of the second link below?

```
` N                  N                  N
 / \                / \                 /\
N   N               N  N               N  N
/\   /\             /\                     /\
N  N  N N           N  N                    N N
                   / \                        /\
                   N  N                       N N
```

I´ve already been to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/04/19/every-binary-tree-there-is/) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654085/generating-all-possible-topologies-in-a-full-binary-tree-having-n-nodes), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870532/all-possible-combinations-of-operations-from-a-given-set-of-numbers-that-total-t/13903423#13903423) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292532/generate-all-structurally-distinct-full-binary-trees-with-n-leaves) but I have tried to implement each and they don´t do what I´m looking for or not explained properly. The first one would be a lot of computation if I have to first generate all possible strings and then parse them to tree type (parent-children relation) and the second one does not print all trees. Because, for instance if I execute by specifying 3 internal nodes like the example above, it just prints one tree(the one on the left).  I know from researching about Catalan numbers that even for a small number of nodes the number of trees grows by a lot but is a useful tool for low number of nodes.

Comment: Just wondering: what is the problem you are trying to solve by figuring the possible "permutations" of objects in binary trees?

Comment: @GhostCat maybe he's trying to find the "optimal" iteration? But then again, the way to solve that would simply be to balance the tree

Comment: @GhostCat right, well I´m building an Ai for a game in which you play with trees and I want it to have all possibilities but in later stages of the game discard trees which are not useful.

Comment: The way you're describing the problem it could have infinite solutions ...

Comment: @Roberto De La Parra sorry, maybe I didn´t explain myself properly. But  not really as you will only  have as number of solutions the nth Catalan number given by (2n)! / (n+1)!n!. So for n = 4 (in this case n is the number of internal nodes) there are 14 possible trees ( see first link). so the Ai knows I have any of those 14 trees.

Comment: I didn’t check all of your links, but it seems to me that some of them have some useful ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I interpret your requirements in this way: You want all binary trees consisting of internal nodes and leaves where every internal node has exactly two children (no node has only one child) and with the given number of leaves.

And no, I don’t know of an algorithm, but I can’t think it would be too hard devising one.

```
List<TreeNode> allBinaryTrees(int numberOfLeaves) {
    if (numberOfLeaves < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number of leaves must be positive");
    }
    List<TreeNode> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (numberOfLeaves == 1) {
        // return a single tree consisting of a single leaf node
        result.add(new Leaf());
        return result;
    }
    // We need one node for the root and at least one for the right subtree,
    // so the size of the left subtree
    // can only go up to numberOfLeaves - 2.
    for (int sizeOfLeftSubtree = 1; sizeOfLeftSubtree < numberOfLeaves - 1; sizeOfLeftSubtree++) {
        List<TreeNode> possibleLeftSubtrees = allBinaryTrees(sizeOfLeftSubtree);
        List<TreeNode> possibleRightSubtrees = allBinaryTrees(numberOfLeaves - sizeOfLeftSubtree);
        for (TreeNode lt : possibleLeftSubtrees) {
            for (TreeNode rt : possibleRightSubtrees) {
                // make a tree of a node with lt and rt as subtrees,
                // and add it to the result
                result.add(new InternalNode(lt, rt));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

In the above I have assumed that `InternalNode` and `Leaf` are both subclasses of `TreeNode`. You may want a different design.