# Prolog: How to generate simple math expressions?

Tags: prolog

I need to write (not calculate) all the states of list of number that means :

Input:

```
Numbers: 1,2,3
Operators: +,-,/,*
```

Output:

```
1+2+3
1-2-3
1/2/3
1*2*3
1+2-3
1+2/3
1+2*3
1-2+3
1-2/3
1-2*3
1/2+3
1/2-3
1/2+3
1*2+3
1*2-3
1+2-3
```

in descend code just show `1+2+3`

How can I develop them to all states?

```
list_sum([Item], Item).
list_sum([Item1,Item2 | Tail], Total) :-
   list_sum([Item1+Item2|Tail], Total).
```

Comment: Is `(1+2)/3` a possibility, or `1/(2-3)`?

Comment: You need to explain: what are the things you show as output, for example, "1+2-3"? Are they compound terms, like `+(1, -(2, 3))` or are they lists like `[1, +, 2, -, 3]` or are they just atoms or strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variation of the nice solution posted by Carlo Capelli allows us to illustrate an useful programming idiom to better exploit first-argument indexing:

```
list_combine([N1| Ns], Os, Nt) :-
    list_combine(Ns, N1, Os, Nt).

list_combine([], N, _, [N]).
list_combine([N2| Ns], N1, Os, [N1, O| Nt]) :-
    member(O, Os),
    list_combine(Ns, N2, Os, Nt).
```

The idea is to pass the list we want to walk by separating the list head from the tail and pass both as argument with the tail as first argument, as exemplified above.

In the original solution, the Prolog compiler will generally not distinguish between a list with just one element and a list with one or more elements. But it will distinguish between an empty list (an atom) and a list with at least one element (a compound term). Note also that the original version creates a spurious choice-point, for each recursive call, on the call to the `list_combine/3` predicate in addition to the intended choice-point on the `member/2` predicate call.

Comment: Thanks, Paulo. Lesson taken :)

Comment: @CapelliC Thanks for opening the door :-)

Answer (score 4):

a simple recursion:

```
list_combine([N|Nr],Os,[N,O|Nt]) :-
    member(O,Os),
    list_combine(Nr,Os,Nt).
list_combine([N],_,[N]).
```

and now

```
?- forall(list_combine([1,2,3],[+,*],C),writeln(C)).
[1,+,2,+,3]
[1,+,2,*,3]
[1,*,2,+,3]
[1,*,2,*,3]
true.
```

here is a - maybe - more readable version

```
list_combine(Ns,Os,Cs) :-
    [N|Nr] = Ns,
    member(O,Os),
    Cs = [N,O|Nt],
    list_combine(Nr,Os,Nt).
```

Of course, use in alternative, just to better understand how unification acts in decomposing and composing arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Using [DCG](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg) with [phrase/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=phrase/2) as a [generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)):

```
operator --> [+].
operator --> [-].
operator --> [*].
operator --> [/].

expr_trinary -->
  [1],
  operator,
  [2],
  operator,
  [3].

expr(E) :-
    phrase(expr_trinary,Expr_trinary),
    atomics_to_string(Expr_trinary,E).
```

Example run:

```
?- expr(E).
E = "1+2+3" ;
E = "1+2-3" ;
E = "1+2*3" ;
E = "1+2/3" ;
E = "1-2+3" ;
E = "1-2-3" ;
E = "1-2*3" ;
E = "1-2/3" ;
E = "1*2+3" ;
E = "1*2-3" ;
E = "1*2*3" ;
E = "1*2/3" ;
E = "1/2+3" ;
E = "1/2-3" ;
E = "1/2*3" ;
E = "1/2/3".
```

---

Since your question works with list, a way to see DCG as list processing is to use [listing/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=listing/1) to convert it to regular Prolog.

```
?- listing(operator).
operator([+|A], A).
operator([-|A], A).
operator([*|A], A).
operator([/|A], A).

true.

?- listing(expr_trinary).
expr_trinary([1|A], B) :-
    operator(A, C),
    C=[2|D],
    operator(D, E),
    E=[3|B].

true.
```

which can be called as regular Prolog.

```
?- expr_trinary(E,[]).
E = [1, +, 2, +, 3] ;
E = [1, +, 2, -, 3] ;
E = [1, +, 2, *, 3] ;
E = [1, +, 2, /, 3] ;
E = [1, -, 2, +, 3] ;
E = [1, -, 2, -, 3] ;
E = [1, -, 2, *, 3] ;
E = [1, -, 2, /, 3] ;
E = [1, *, 2, +, 3] ;
E = [1, *, 2, -, 3] ;
E = [1, *, 2, *, 3] ;
E = [1, *, 2, /, 3] ;
E = [1, /, 2, +, 3] ;
E = [1, /, 2, -, 3] ;
E = [1, /, 2, *, 3] ;
E = [1, /, 2, /, 3].
```

---

An expanded solution using a number (1,2,3) in any position:

```
number --> [1].
number --> [2].
number --> [3].

operator --> [+].
operator --> [-].
operator --> [*].
operator --> [/].

expr_trinary -->
  number,
  operator,
  number,
  operator,
  number.  

expr(E) :-
    phrase(expr_trinary,Expr_trinary),
    atomics_to_string(Expr_trinary,E).
```

Example run:

```
?- expr(E).
E = "1+1+1" ;
E = "1+1+2" ;
E = "1+1+3" ;
E = "1+1-1" ;
E = "1+1-2" ;
E = "1+1-3" ;
...
```

For a explanation of how to generate with DCG see this [Amzi](http://www.amzi.com/) section: [Generating with Difference Lists](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/pro/ref_dcg.htm#GeneratingWithDifferenceLists)

---

In comment for other answer you wrote:

> its not work more than 3 element? can you develop it for more elements?

As the number of elements increases so does the [combinatorial explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion).

To keep the combinatorial explosion down for the example run this will only use two numbers (1,2) and two operators (+,*), you can add more to your liking.

```
number(1) --> [1].
number(2) --> [2].

operator(+) --> [+].
operator(*) --> [*].

expr(N) --> number(N).
expr((E1,Op,E2)) --> operator(Op),expr(E1),expr(E2).

expr(E) :-
    length(Expr,_),
    phrase(expr(E),Expr).
```

Note that this uses [length/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=length/2) for [iterative deepening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search). Basically `length/2` generates list of increasing length and then [phrase/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=phrase/2) comes up with answers that are of that length.

```
?- length(Ls,N).
Ls = [],
N = 0 ;
Ls = [_870],
N = 1 ;
Ls = [_870, _876],
N = 2 ;
Ls = [_870, _876, _882],
N = 3 ;
Ls = [_870, _876, _882, _888],
N = 4 ;
Ls = [_870, _876, _882, _888, _894],
N = 5 ;
Ls = [_870, _876, _882, _888, _894, _900],
N = 6 
...
```

So that generator works as expected the normal [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) and DCG, e.g.

```
<expr> ::= <expr> <op> <expr>

expr((E1,Op,E2)) --> expr(E1),operator(Op),expr(E2).
```

which is [direct left recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion) is converted to this

```
<expr> ::= <op> <expr> <expr>

expr((E1,Op,E2)) --> operator(Op),expr(E1),expr(E2).
```

Example run:

```
?- expr(E).
E = 1 ;
E = 2 ;
E =  (1, (+), 1) ;
E =  (1, (+), 2) ;
E =  (2, (+), 1) ;
E =  (2, (+), 2) ;
E =  (1, (*), 1) ;
E =  (1, (*), 2) ;
E =  (2, (*), 1) ;
E =  (2, (*), 2) ;
E =  (1, (+), 1, (+), 1) ;
...
E =  (1, (+), 2, (+), 2, (*), 1) ;
E =  (1, (+), 2, (+), 2, (*), 2) ;
E =  (1, (+), (1, (+), 1), (+), 1) ;
E =  (1, (+), (1, (+), 1), (+), 2) ;
E =  (1, (+), (1, (+), 2), (+), 1) ;
...
```

Comment: Downvoted because there is absolutely no reason to provide the operators as facts/predicates.

Answer (score 1):

One way is

```
get_calcul([X], _, Temp, Calcul):-
    append(Temp, [X], Calcul).

get_calcul([N|T], [Op|Top], Temp, Out) :-
    append(Temp, [N, Op], Temp1),
   get_calcul(T, Top, Temp1, Out).

all_operations(In, Out) :-
   setof(Op, X^Ops^(permutation([+,-,*,/], X), get_calcul(In, X, [], Ops), atomic_list_concat(Ops, Op)), Out).
```

Result

```
?- all_operations([1,2,3], Out).
Out = ['1*2+3', '1*2-3', '1*2/3', '1+2*3', '1+2-3', '1+2/3', '1-2*3', '1-2+3', '1-2/3'|...].
```

**Well, I solved my problem, not your's !**

This can be done :

```
member_(In, X) :-
    member(X, In).

get_calcul([N], _, Temp, Out) :-
    append(Temp, [N], Out).

get_calcul([N|T], [Op|Top], Temp, Out) :-
    append(Temp, [N, Op], Temp1),
   get_calcul(T, Top, Temp1, Out).

all_operations(In, Out) :-
    % if you have N numbers
    length(In, Len),
    % you need N-1 operators
    LenOps is Len - 1,
    length(LOps, LenOps),
   setof(Op, LOps^Ops^(maplist(member_([+,-,*,/]), LOps),get_calcul(In, LOps, [], Ops), atomic_list_concat(Ops, Op)), Out).
```

For example :

```
 ?- all_operations([1,2,3], Out), maplist(writeln, Out).
1*2*3
1*2+3
1*2-3
1*2/3
1+2*3
1+2+3
1+2-3
1+2/3
1-2*3
1-2+3
1-2-3
1-2/3
1/2*3
1/2+3
1/2-3
1/2/3
Out = ['1*2*3', '1*2+3', '1*2-3', '1*2/3', '1+2*3', '1+2+3', '1+2-3', '1+2/3', '1-2*3'|...].
```

Comment: what about  ['1+2+3','1*2*3','1/2/3','1-2-3'] ??

Comment: its not work more than 3 element? can you develop it for more elemnts?

Answer (score 1):

[image]This my solution proposal, which I find to be very simple and straight forward, copy and paste below to notepad++ editor to get best readability.

```
* ________________________________________________                           *
*|find_expression(NumsList,TargetValue,Expression)|                          *
**------------------------------------------------*                          *
* Expression is an arithmetic expression of the numbers in Numslist with     *
* possible operators '+','-','*','/' and '(' and ')' between the numbers     *
*  in such a way that the expression evaluates to the TargetValue argument   *  
*****************************************************************************/%

/* a single element number list can evaluate only to itself */ 
find_expression([SingleNumber],SingleNumber,SingleNumber).

/* expression of a multypile number list */ 
find_expression(NumberList,Target,Expression):-

/* non-deterministically  divide the number list 
 into 2 separate lists which include at least one number each*/ 
append([X|Xs],[Y|Ys], NumberList),

/* recursively find an expression for east list, 
   where the expression evaluates to itself */ 
find_expression([X|Xs],Exp1,Exp1),
find_expression([Y|Ys],Exp2,Exp2),

/* non-deterministically  choose an operand from [+,-,*,division] 
   and compose Expression to be (Exp1 Operand Exp2) */ 
(   member(Expression,[Exp1+Exp2,Exp1-Exp2,Exp1*Exp2]) 
    ; /* prevent zero divison */
    (Val2 is Exp2, Val2 =\= 0, Expression = (Exp1/Exp2))), %/*

/* assure that final expression evaluates(matches) the target value 
   and convert value from integer to float if necessary */
( Target = Expression ; Target is Expression 
  ; FloatTarget is Target*1.0, FloatTarget is Expression).
```